# SSL Handshake failing for Eureka Discovery Client

Tags: ssl, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have been able to setup and successfully validate the Spring cloud setup using Eureka + ZUUL + Ribbon + Config Server over HTTP.

However when i tried moving to the HTTPS, individual services are running fine over HTTPS, but the Eureka Client Discovery is failing.

Below is my application.yml for Eureka Server and Client (In this case ZUUL) -

Eureka:

```
server:
  port: 8761
  ssl:
    key-store: 
      ${PATH}certFile.ini
    key-store-password: 
      ~Sample7~
    trust-store: 
      ${PATH}certFile.ini
    trust-store-password: 
      ~Sample7~
    keyStoreType: 
      XXXXXX
    keyAlias: 
      signingKey
    ciphers: 
      TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    protocol: 
      TLS

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: 
      localhost
    securePort: 
      8761
    securePortEnabled: 
      true
    nonSecurePortEnabled: 
      false
    secureVirtualHostName: Discovery Server
    homePageUrl: 
      https://127.0.0.1:8761/eureka/
    statusPageUrl: https://127.0.0.1:8761/eureka/admin/info
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
```

Eureka Client:

```
server:
  port: 8010
  ssl:
      enabled: 
        true
      key-store:
          ${PATH}certFile.ini
      key-store-password:
          ~Sample7~
      trust-store:
          ${PATH}certFile.ini
      trust-store-password:
          ~Sample7~
      keyStoreType:
          XXXXXX
      keyAlias:
          signingKey
      ciphers:
          TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
      protocol:
          TLS

eureka:
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: https://127.0.0.1:8761/eureka/
        healthcheck:
            enabled: true
        lease:
            duration: 5
spring:
    application:
      name: apigateway
ribbon:
  ConnectTimeout: 60000
  ReadTimeout: 600000

hystrix:
    command:
        default:
            execution:
                timeout:
                    enabled: false
                isolation:
                    strategy: THREAD
                    thread:
                        timeoutInMilliseconds: 60000
```

Now when i start the Eureka Server, it gets up on https, however when trying to run the client application i get below error-

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.delete(WebResource.java:591) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.cancel(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:76) ~[eureka-client-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:74) [eureka-client-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71) [eureka-client-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:74) [eureka-client-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118) ~[eureka-client-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79) ~[eureka-client-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71) [eureka-client-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:74) [eureka-client-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:119) [eureka-client-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71) [eureka-client-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$2.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:74) [eureka-client-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) [eureka-client-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.cancel(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:71) [eureka-client-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.unregister(DiscoveryClient.java:902) [eureka-client-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.shutdown(DiscoveryClient.java:880) [eureka-client-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$a84c8cb4.invoke(<generated>) [eureka-client-1.4.11.jar:1.4.11]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.config.StandardBeanLifecycleDecorator$2.invoke(StandardBeanLifecycleDecorator.java:85) [spring-cloud-context-1.1.3.RELEASE.jar:1.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$92dcbb78.shutdown(<generated>) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) [spring-aop-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy88.shutdown(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration.onApplicationEvent(EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration.java:192) [spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:253) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:174) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:137) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:382) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:336) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:989) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.admin.SpringApplicationAdminMXBeanRegistrar$SpringApplicationAdmin.shutdown(SpringApplicationAdminMXBeanRegistrar.java:126) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:193) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.invokeWithOpenReturn(ConvertingMethod.java:175) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:117) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(MXBeanIntrospector.java:54) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682) [na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:553) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:412) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:179) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:612) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:117) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55) ~[httpclient-4.5.2.jar:4.5.2]
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    ... 98 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    ... 116 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    ... 122 common frames omitted
```

Any suggestions with what i might be missing in this?

Br

Comment: `server.ssl` is for the embedded container (tomcat, jetty etc..) not for the client connecting to eureka.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you don't import the certificate into your JVM. It bothers me too for I just can't do importing in our production JVMs.
My solution is to make a custom **EurekaJerseyClient** to replace the default one in **DiscoveryClient**.

This has to be done because the default **EurekaJerseyClient** will use the default ssl context in apache http client, but not the one you set using **SSLContext.setDefault(sslContext)** or **HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory())**. So does the **HostnameVerifier**.

I asked the same question and post the answer myself. You can check it [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42289196/how-to-override-spring-cloud-eureka-default-discovery-client-default-ssl-context).

Answer (score 1):

You shoud config ssl for ribbon:

```
ribbon.TrustStore= etc/keystore.jks
ribbon.TrustStorePassword= 123456aA@
ribbon.ReadTimeout= 60000
ribbon.IsSecure= true
ribbon.MaxAutoRetries= 2
```