# Eureka Discovery Client add self signed certificates

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, netflix-eureka

I have couple of services in spring boot which register them self with eureka server.

These services work fine on http. However when I use https Client registration fails because of SSL validation.

How I can add my self signed jks file in DiscoveryClient to trust the https certificates?

Edit

My application.yml file

```
    spring:
  application:
    name: docker-prototype-user-profile

server:
  port: 8301
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: https://localhost:8761/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
```

My application.properties file

```
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keypair.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=123456
server.ssl.key-password=123456
```

Here jks file is the same as in eureka server. 
I am using same key for https across all services. As jks file contain public and private key so here it is used for 2 purposes. 1st is to provide private key for https of this service. 2ndly I want to use this as certificate in eureka discovery client.

```
keytool -genkeypair \
   -keystore keypair.jks \
  -dname "CN=OLEKSIYS-W3T, OU=Sun Java System Application Server, O=Sun Microsystems, L=Santa Clara, ST=California, C=US" \
  -keypass 123456 \
  -storepass 123456 \
  -keyalg RSA \
  -keysize 2048 \
  -alias default \
  -ext SAN=DNS:localhost,DNS:docker-prototype,DNS:docker-prototype-authentication,DNS:docker-prototype-eureka-server,DNS:docker-prototype-post-management,DNS:docker-prototype-secure-service,DNS:docker-prototype-user-management,DNS:docker-prototype-user-profile,DNS:docker-prototype-zuul-gateway \
  -validity 9999
```

keypair is generated using above command

Comment: Would you please share client config file

Comment: I have added configuration file.

Comment: RestTemplate works fine with custom HttpClient but DiscoveryClient use its own HttpClient. 
I have tried to inject sslContext using https://stackoverflow.com/a/49988212/8019011 but this causes Exception with following message
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient]: Factory method 'eurekaClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!